# Deserializing JSON in case of multiple types

Tags: java, json, gson

My program receives as input json strings as the following ones:

```
{ ..., "source": [ {"Web": {"id": 10, fields_a} }], ... }
{ ..., "source": [ {"Device": {"id": 22, fields_b} }], ... }
```

i.e., in the field `source` I can have various types of sources. These sources share some attributes, for example `id`, but differ in the others `fields_a`, `fields_b`.

I am using `gson` for serializing/deserializing and I would like to keep things as simple as possible. I created a hierarchy of classes for each type of source by creating a base class `Source` with all the shared attributes and several child classes with the specific attributes, but the deserialization is not able to manage the various types.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "but the deserialization is not able to manage the various types" - could you elaborate on what this means? Could you paste your deserialisation code?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have one Java class corresponding to any json 'object' I receive. However, the elements in 'source' can be of different type, and I really do not know how to deserialize in that case.

Comment: If you want to keep things "as simple as possible" just deserialize into Lists and Maps.